# MySQL Insert with Select

Tags: mysql

Trying to insert data to a table with values from different tables.

```
  INSERT INTO class_teachers_section(class_ref, teachers_ref, section_ref) 
   select (select class.id as class_ref from class where class.name = 'pe'), 
   (select teachers.id as teachers_ref from teachers where teachers.last_name       
    = 'lenevo'), 
   (select section.id as section_ref from section where section.name = 'grade 4')
```

It's only inserting `class_ref` values, what's wrong with my code?

Tried this.

```
INSERT INTO class_teachers_section(class_ref, teachers_ref, section_ref)
    values( (select class.id as class_ref from class where class.name = 'pe'),
           (select teachers.id as teachers_ref from teachers where    
            teachers.last_name    = 'lenevo'),
          (select section.id as section_ref from section 
           where section.name = 'grade 4'))
```

`teachers_ref` can not be null error.

Comment: Does the query return any value?

select teachers.id as teachers_ref from teachers where    
            teachers.last_name    = 'lenevo'

Comment: yes it is  ....  its working now  ...  MySQL sometimes acts differently hehe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

```
INSERT INTO class_teachers_section(class_ref, teachers_ref, section_ref) 
SELECT a.class_ref, b.teachers_ref, c.section_ref
      FROM
      (select class.id as class_ref from class where class.name = 'pe') as a,
      (select teachers.id as teachers_ref from teachers where teachers.last_name = 'lenevo') as b, 
      (select section.id as section_ref from section where section.name = 'grade 4') as c;
```

I assume it will be quiet slow, but should to the trick.